# CaCurrentMediaTime conversion to it's date and string counterparts

Tags: ios, datetime, core-data, nsdate, quartz-core

I'm trying to get the exact time and date when users select a button, and then again when they deselect it.

I've been using NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970 so far. This gets me miliseconds (floats), which are easy to convert to an NSDate and then to a string. However i've noticed several times now that this gives no absolute time with differences of up to 1 or 2 minutes compared to real time on my Iphone 4S.

The reason for using floats with miliseconds here is because it makes it easy to send to different methods allowing it to save to Core Data in an NSNumber and thus allowing easy calculations later on.

I've found a post on here suggesting the use of CACurrentMediaTime as such but I have been unsuccesful in converting it to a date and a string of that date:

```
double CurrentTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
```

NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow 
gives the right date except that the clock on the simulator is about 35 to 45 minutes ahead of what it actually is on my mac.

Current conversion goes like this:

```
NSDate *conversion = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:startTimeInMiliSeconds];
NSDateFormatter *formatter;
NSString        *dateString;
formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:conversion];
```

Any ideas/references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just save `NSDate`s in Core Data and omit the whole conversion process? `NSDate`s are a natural datatype for Core-Data entries.

Comment: I had been thinking about it but now i've been forced to resort to this anyhow. The floats with miliseconds had some little bug. I made a cycle button to cycle through all entries using an increment so I could easily check if my core data works. But on every cycle it recalculcated the time on the second time. I changed float to nsdate's, no changes to core data code and now it works. Very weird. All that is left now is to get the nsdate's standard GMT to follow the users' timezone. Accepting because this is the way to go, thanks!